# Why does the Clausius inequality say entropy is closed cycle < zero?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, heat-engine

I am not understanding how can clausius inequality say (closed)$\int{\frac{dQ}{T}}<0$.

How does this not violate the second law? In closed cycle, entropy of a system should be either zero or greater than zero. What's wrong here?

Comment: Have a read of [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clausius_theorem).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inequality you cite is actually correct (for an irreversible process path). It is your interpretation that is the problem. The left hand side is not the entropy change of the system. The entropy change is the right hand side of the inequality (i.e., zero). In a cycle, whether reversible or irreversible, the entropy change is zero. This is because the initial state at the beginning of the cycle is the same as the final state at the end of a cycle, and, since entropy is the function of state, its change is zero.

The left hand side should read
$$\int{\frac{dq}{T_{boundary}}}$$where $T_{boundary}$
is the temperature at the boundary between the system and its surroundings (through which the heat dq flows from the surroundings to the system).  The correct form of the equation for both reversible and irreversible process paths of a cycle is $$\int{\frac{dq}{T_{boundary}}}\leq 0=\Delta S$$

More generally, in any arbitrary irreversible process of a closed system, the integral is always less than the entropy change of the system.